# Heat Death and Energy potential

Tags: thermodynamics

Given that no energy potential exist after heat death is achieved, my question is that is there a system in real world with absolutely no energy potential at all? Or does it only happen theoretically?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you put boundaries on your system, yes. A pool of water that reaches a uniform temperature and cannot interact with anything else has none of what I would call *exergy,* and you are calling energy potential. Same with a gas in a closed box.

At heat death of the universe, all matter will be very far apart and will cool down to the temperature of the vacuum, so no temperature gradient will be there to cause a net energy flux, and no work can be done or extracted.